# What makes 'Every boy's teacher is proud of his achievement' grammatically wrong?

Tags: binding-theory

I came across the following contrast while I was studying English syntax about binding theory.

1. John's[1] mother is proud of his[1] achievements.
2. *Every boy's[1] teacher is proud of his[1] achievements.

In 1) the possessive pronoun can be coindexed with the antecedent John. However, it is ungrammatical to coindex the antecedent 'every boy' with the possessive pronoun 'his' in sentence 2). Could anyone explain the grammricality of 1) and ungrammaticality of 2) in terms of the binding theory?

Comment: I can’t explain the ungrammaticality of 2, because to me it’s perfectly grammatical. I don’t see what the problem with it is supposed to be. It’s ambiguous, of course, since ‘his’ could just as well be coindexed with the teacher himself, but that doesn’t make it ungrammatical. (As a question, it’s also off-topic here, but it would be perfectly on-topic on [english.se].)

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet — it’s grammatical for me also.

Comment: I really appreciate your valuable answer. This question was part of a syntax question in an exam.

Comment: The question is asking about the linguistic explanation for the alleged ungrammatically in terms of a specific syntactic theory, not just whether or not the sentence is grammatical in English, and therefore fits perfectly well on this site.

Comment: It's not ungrammatical. It (and sentences like it) appear in grammar books because they're **ambiguous**, in ways we can explain by the use of quantifiers like _every_. If it's marked as ungrammatical, check to see whether it's only ungrammatical under a specific reading.

Comment: I guess I made some people uncomfortable because my question seemed like just asking the ungrammaticality of a sentence. I kind of sensed that the sentence was correct but because it was on a syntax exam marked as ungrammatical and the exam required to give a syntactic explanation, I had spent almost 5 hours searching through books before I posted the question here. Maybe I should have made the question look more like it was related to linguistics. But thanks for all the answers. I couldn't find the way to select an answer to be taken as an accepted answer. Well the question is closed now.